# DataTrigger in CellTemplate binding to HeaderTemplate; can it work?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatrigger

The goal here would be to check all grid checkboxes if the header checkbox changes:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="InnerBox">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True"
                         Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                         ElementName=HeaderCheckbox}">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="False"
                         Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                         ElementName=HeaderCheckbox}">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <!-- col1 -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- header check -->
                    <CheckBox Name="HeaderCheckbox" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- body check -->
                    <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource InnerBox}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!-- col2 -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Text" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <!-- sample data -->
    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>2</sys:String>
    <sys:String>3</sys:String>
</DataGrid>
```

Looks like:

[image: Screen]

For some reason, the trigger does not fire.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ElementName` binding inside a `DataTemplate` can't reach an element outside of the template as you noticed. This is because it can be instantiated many times and has its own namescope so any `ElementName` binding you create inside a `DataTemplate` will look inside the template for another element with that name.

Looking at it with Snoop we can also see that a `RelativeSource` binding can't be used directly since they are in different parts of the Visual Tree

[image]

The only thing that I can think of to get around this is to bind both of the CheckBoxes to a common ancestor, e.g. the parent `DataGrid` and use an attached property or the `Tag` property. Example

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="InnerBox">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True"
                     Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                       Path=Tag}">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and

```
<DataTemplate>
    <!-- header check -->
    <CheckBox Name="HeaderCheckbox"
              IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                  Path=Tag,
                                  Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Clever, and if Tag is used, you can add an Attached Property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regular DataBinding to the `HeaderCheckBox` is possible because the `CheckBox` exists as part of a `Template`, and it is in a different branch of the `VisualTree` than the `DataGridItems`

Usually I make it the reverse: When the header `CheckBox` gets checked, check all the row `CheckBoxes`. My main reason for this is because the CheckBoxes are usually there so users can check/uncheck them, and if they're bound to the header CheckBox checked state, then the user can't alter them.

For implementing that, I usually hook into the `Click` or `Checked` event of the Header CheckBox.

If the row `CheckBox.IsChecked` state is bound to something in a ViewModel, I'll hook the event to a `Command` in my ViewModel, and set the data item that the `CheckBox.IsChecked` is bound to to `true`/`false` depending on the header CheckBox state (usually passed in as a `CommandParameter`)

If the `CheckBox.IsChecked` state is not bound to anything, you can use regular code-behind to loop through your `DataGrid.Items`, use the `ItemContainerGenerator` to get the ItemContainer for each item, find the `CheckBox`, and then set it's check state.

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer doesn't make sense to me. The question is about DataTriggers in the CellTemplate binding to the HeaderTemplate. I'm not using Commands or a ViewModel in the question. I guess I am really just wondering if this can be done. I realize using things other than triggers can do the same thing. I'm sorry I wasn't more clear in my question.

Comment: @Jerry I'm sure it's possible, but it would require some highly unusual workarounds, such as a Converter that searches the Visual Tree for the Header CheckBox. I would recommend that you re-evaluate what you are trying to accomplish before heading down that path and check for alternatives.

Comment: I don't think regular DataBinding to the HeaderCheckBox is possible because the CheckBox exists in a Template, and it is in a different branch of the VisualTree than the DataGridItems